# Java loop and file generation

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

I'm new to java. Dont know how to loop and generate the below file txt file based on available data. The data is available in hashmap (genData()) as list of elements and i need to loop map to get the list and generate the file. Expected result of the file (Myfile.txt) is attached as sample in the post.

Note: A single stringbuilder function should handle both the Hashmap data.

Finally, genFile() method will generate the file.

[Myfile.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4dUI.png)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileGen gen= new FileGen ();
        StringBuilder resultbuffer = new StringBuilder();
        resultbuffer.append(gen.genAppleTxt());
        resultbuffer.append(gen.genSamsungTxt());
        gen.genFile(resultbuffer.toString());
    }

     private Map<String,List<Mobile>> genData(){
     Map<String,List<Mobile>> hMap=new HashMap<>();
     hMap.put("Apple", List<Mobile>); //List of Mobile elements with size 2
     hMap.put("Samsung", List<Mobile>); //List of Mobile elements with size 1

     }

    private StringBuilder genAppleTxt() {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        buffer.append("==========================================================");
        buffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        buffer.append("                  Type " + "1");
        buffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        buffer.append("                  ********");
        buffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        buffer.append("Spec" + "\t" + "(Apple Models)");
        buffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        buffer.append("---------");
        buffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        buffer.append("Model\t\t SIM\t\t Weight\t\t Price\t\t Color");
        buffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        buffer.append("8Plus\t\t Single\t\t 202g\t\t $480\t\t Coral\t\t");
        buffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        buffer.append("Ip11\t\t Single\t\t 194g\t\t $700\t\t Silver\t\t");
        buffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        return buffer;

    }

    private StringBuilder genSamsungTxt() {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        buffer.append("==========================================================");
        buffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        buffer.append("                  Type " + "2");
        buffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        buffer.append("                  ********");
        buffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        buffer.append("Spec" + "\t" + "(Samsung Models)");
        buffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        buffer.append("---------");
        buffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        buffer.append("Model\t\t SIM\t\t Weight\t\t Price\t\t Color");
        buffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        buffer.append("S8\t\t\t Dual\t\t 155g\t\t $243\t\t Pink\t\t");
        buffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        buffer.append("==========================================================");
        return buffer;

    }

    private void genFile(String toWrite) throws IOException {
        File tmpFile = new File("<MyPath>\\MyFile.txt");
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(tmpFile)) {
            writer.write(toWrite);
        }
    }
```

Please help with a looping logic and on how to generate a txt file as provided in sample.

Comment: Whats `myClass`? This will not compile.

Comment: @ TA changed the class name

Comment: You didn’t ask a question. You only told us that you are unsure.